# useEffect getting called twice React JS

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

So I have a route to my component(Submissions) in my App.js file/ App component, wrapped in a couple conditionals.

```
function App() {
  if (auth0Context.user && isAuthenticated) {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
          <Router history={ history }>
            { !email_verified
              ? <Route path={ ["*"] } component={ EmailNotVerified } />
              : (
                <div>
                  <Route path="/submissions" component={ Submissions } />
                </div>
              )
            }
          </Router>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
          <Router history={ history }>
          </Router>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

For some reason `useEffect` is getting called twice in this `Submissions` component:

```
function Submissions() {

  const [user, setUser] = useState('');
  const [data, setData] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState('');

  const auth0Context = useContext(Auth0Context);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        let auth0User = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/getAuth0User/${ auth0Context.user.sub }`);
        setUser(auth0User.data);
        console.log(auth0User.data.app_metadata.roles);
        const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/getSubmissions/`);
        setData(response.data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
    fetchData()
  }, []);

  if (user) {
    if (user.app_metadata.roles == "Admin") {
      return (
        <div>
          <ul>
            { data.length && data.map((data, index) => {
              return (
                <div key={ index }>
                  <Row>
                    <Col xs="8">
                      <Card>
                        <CardBody>
                          <CardTitle>
                            <b>Title: </b>
                            { data.title }
                          </CardTitle>
                        </CardBody>
                        <CardBody>
                          <CardImg style={ { width: "300px", height: "300px" } } src={ data.path }>
                          </CardImg>
                        </CardBody>
                        <CardBody>
                          <CardText><b>Type: </b>{ data.type }</CardText>
                        </CardBody>
                      </Card>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </div>
              )
            }) }
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    }
  } else {
    return (
      <div></div>
    );
  }
};

export default Submissions;
```

Comment: useContext ... it could cause a rerender of the whole component...

Comment: I removed it and I'm still getting the same issue?

Comment: Hmm... Your `useEffect` should theoretically not re-run since you've passed an empty dependency array. I can't see anything obvious, but I'll keep looking.

Comment: Check if anywhere in the core (usually it is in index.js) there is a component React.StrictMode - it causes components to render twice in development build

Answer (score 0):

O wow. I figured out I was loading my component twice in App.js

```
if (auth0Context.user && isAuthenticated) {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
       <Router history={history}>
       <Route path="/submissions" component={Submissions}/>
        {!email_verified ? 
        <Route path={["*"]} component={EmailNotVerified} />
         :
         <div>
          <Route exact path="/submissions" component={Submissions}/>
         </div>
      }
      </Router>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
} else {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
       <Router history={history}>
       </Router>
      </div>
     </BrowserRouter>
   )

}
```

Comment: Can you either explain in more detail or add more code? How are you loading your component twice?

Answer (score -1):

Somehow your component is getting rendered twice - like unmounted and mounted again. There are a couple things that could be causing this:

1. In your submissions route, you are not using `exact`, which means that navigating from `/submissions` to `/submissions/foo` would cause a rerender. Try adding `exact` to `<Route path="/submissions"... />`
2. You have some conditional logic `if (auth0Context.user && isAuthenticated)` which could be going from `true -> false -> true`, which would cause a rerender.

My main advice is ditch the conditional routing. I have found that using conditional routing is tedious and error prone and can lead to unnecessary rerenders at the app level. Instead, your app should do all of it's initialization stuff early before rendering your router (user/token validation, email verification, etc). Then, once you're ready, render your router and the rest of the app. Here's a super basic example:

```
const LoginPage = () => { ... }
const AppRoutes = ({ user }) => {
  return (
    <UserContext user={user}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route ... />
        <Route ... />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </UserContext>
  )
}

const MainApp = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  
  // check whether the user is logged in... however you do that in your app
  useEffect(async () => {
    const userInfo = await validateAuthToken()
    if(userInfo) setUser(userInfo)
    setIsLoading(false)
  }, []);

  if(isLoading) return <Loader />
  if(user) return <AppRoutes user={user} />
  return <LoginPage />
}
```

Comment: I didn't even notice the multiple BrowserRouters

Comment: Well, it's not the "multiple" so much as the conditional logic around your router OR routes. Don't do that. Just render all of your routes, and then in each of your components check if the user is authenticated. I'll update the answer to show what I mean.

Comment: I've personally never had to scaffold authentication in `react-router` so I'm curious to see the right way to do this

Comment: I removed the conditional rendering and still the same issue @RyanWheale

Comment: Thanks for formatting your code. I have updated my answer. In your case, don't even render the routes until the email has been verified (use my code as kind of a guide).